# is there a better way for me to write a script for quiz in shell

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I have been at this script for 24 hours and I am getting nowhere. I am so desperate for help.

I am trying to create a quiz and I need the switches to verify if the user's input matches the 3 options; 'Y' 'N' 'G' and if true move to the next question. If not, I need the switch to then prompt the user of the default output each time the user enter's anything else besides those 3 options.

Comment: If it's not working, then yes there is probably a better way. But unless you show what you have done, it's quite hard to help you ...

Comment: `$Host.UI.PromptForChoice(...)` sounds like a good fit for your use case

Answer (score 0):

```
function Test-statement ($Y,$N,$G,$YY,$NN,$GG){

    $check = $Y -eq $YY

    $check =$check -and ($N -eq $NN)

    $check =$check -and ($G -eq $GG)

    $check
}

$questions = @{

    "what is the current year now" = @('2023','2023','2023')
    "what is the previous year" = @('2022','2022','2022')
    
    }

 foreach ($key in $questions.keys) {
    $check = $false
    do{
        
        write-host ("$key" + "?")
        $Y = read-host "1"
        $N = read-host "2"
        $G = read-host "3"
        $YY = $questions.$key[0]
        $NN = $questions.$key[1]
        $GG = $questions.$key[2]
        $check = Test-statement $Y $N $G $YY $NN $GG
        if (!($check)){write-host "not true" -ForegroundColor red}

    
    } until ($check)
}
```